# conkeror install fails on OS x lion

Tags: installation, osx-lion, conkeror

I installed Conkeror by following directions from the Conkeror wiki at http://conkeror.org/InstallationOSX

I am using xulrunner 6.0, which is installed in /Library/Frameworks/XUL.framework/

After completing the install directions listed on the wiki and attempting to start Conkeror:

```
/Applications/conkeror.mozdev.org/conkeror.app/Contents/MacOS/xulrunner -foreground www.Yahoo.com
```

I get the following error:

```
Could not find the Mozilla runtime.
```

The same error results when I click on conkeror.app

The install worked on my Leopard machine at work, but not on Lion for some reason. xulrunner 6 runtime is not being picked up by conkeror for some reason?